# Jquery Form Validation: Display all errors in a specific section of the webpage

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, jquery-plugins

I'm using JQuery's validation plugin to validate a HTML form. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

By default, all validation errors right next to the input.
Is it possible to display a list of all errors towards the top of the page, and what code what I use to do this?

Answer (score 4):

According to the options you can provide for this plugin (see http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options), you can specify the `errorLabelContainer` and `errorContainer` options, where it will group the error messages into a single or multiple containers.

Sample taken from site:

```
<ul id="messageBox"></ul>
```

```
$("#myform").validate({
   errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox",
   wrapper: "li",
   submitHandler: function() { alert("Submitted!") }
})
```